# how to keep the value of dropdowns while navigating in jsp application?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

```html
<li class="dropdown active">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><b>Title</b><span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:#b3ffb3;">
                            <li><a href="i.jsp"><b>1</b></a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="2.jsp"><b>2</b></a></li> 
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="3.jsp"><b>3</b></a></li> 
                            
                     
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

above is my dropdowns and navigation. when i navigate to other page by clicking 1, 2,3 it resets dropdowns in my form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution for this.

below is the code to maintain session

```js
   // Run on page load
    window.onload = function() {

        // If sessionStorage is storing default values (ex. name), exit the function and do not restore data
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('Environment') == "Environment" ) {
            return;
        }

        // If values are not blank, restore them to the fields
        var Environment = sessionStorage.getItem('Environment');
        if (Environment !== null) $('#Environment').val(Environment);

        var DataFilter = sessionStorage.getItem('DataFilter');
        if (DataFilter !== null) $('#DataFilter').val(DataFilter);

        var InUse= sessionStorage.getItem('InUse');
        if (InUse!== null) $('#InUse').val(InUse);

        var DataUsage= sessionStorage.getItem('DataUsage');
        if (DataUsage!== null) $('#DataUsage').val(DataUsage);
    }

    // Before refreshing the page, save the form data to sessionStorage
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem("Environment", $('#Environment').val());
        sessionStorage.setItem("DataFilter", $('#DataFilter').val());
        sessionStorage.setItem("InUse", $('#InUse').val());
        sessionStorage.setItem("DataUsage", $('#DataUsage').val());
    }
```